# GGanimate Fourier series

Tags: r, gganimate

So i found this script somewhere and im trying it out.
Its working fine, the plot script is running but i cant get the Fourier series to converge to the function.

Here is the script:

```
library(ggtext)
library(gganimate)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(gifski)

fourier_approx_2 <- function(x,k){
  n <- 0:k
  a_0 <- 0
  a_n <- 0
  b_n <- ifelse(n==0,0,-((-1)^n -1)*200*(n*pi)^-1)
  
  fourier <- 0
  
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    
    fourier[i] <- a_0 +
      sum(a_n*cos(0:(length(n)-1)*pi/3 * x[i]))
      sum(a_n*sin(0:(length(n)-1)*pi/3 * x[i]))
  }
  
  return(fourier)
}

x <- seq(-0.01,3,by= 0.001)
k <- 0:75

p <- tibble(X=rep(x,length(k)),
            K = rep(k,each=length(x))) %>%
    mutate(Fou = pmap_dbl(list(X, K), fourier_approx_2)) %>%
  mutate(K = as.factor(K)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X,Fou))+
  geom_point(data=tibble(x), aes(x=x,y=100),col="red")+
  geom_point(size=0.5 , show.legend = F, col="white")+ 
  labs(title = "Fourier aproximation<b style='color:#808080'> of</b><b style='color:#E60026'> f(x)</b>",
       subtitle = 'First {closest_state} partial sums')+
  ylab("f(x)")+theme_ft_rc()+
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown() )+
  transition_states(K)

animate(p,nframes = length(k)*2+100, end_pause = 100, rewind = F,renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

In the plot I get red line in the right place (the function f(x)) and for the Fourier series I get a flat line (white) and i dont understand where is the problem.
Any guess?

Comment: you are missing the ´data´ parameter for  ´geom_point(size=0.5 , show.legend = F, col="white")´

Comment: I think its not the problem, cuz in where i found it its was already missing and it worked